# Графики. C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Какую библиотеку или может встроенный модуль использоваться для построения таких сложных графиков. И возможностью потом сохранить его в pdf формате Желательно с ссылкой на примеры и документацию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слышал вот про [это (OxyPlot)](http://www.oxyplot.org/), но не юзал

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам использовать OxyPLot(как уже заметил уважаемый @tym32167). Библиотека отлично работает для `wpf` и `finworms` и очень просто сохраняет как в `pdf` так и в `png`. Приведу пример для winforms.

1 - установить через менеджер пакетов `OxyPlot.WindowsForms`.

2 - если в `ToolBox` не появился `PlotView` то нужно в `ToolBox` ПКМ ->`Сhoose Items...`->`.NET Framework Components` -> `Browse` выбрать `OxyPlot.WindowsForms.dll` из папки `packages` вашего проекта.

2.1 если вылетает ошибка, наподобии `There are no components in ..` то нужно в папку где лежит `OxyPlot.WindowsForms.dll` добавить `OxyPlot.dll` из папки `OxyPlot.Core.X.X.X`. Возможно придется несколько раз повторить.

3 - Создать контейнер для `PlotView` (не обязательно но желательно) например `TableLayoutPanel` и поместить в его ячейку `PlotView` обзываем его например -`volumePlot`.

4 - в `codeBehind` :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var _fileData = new DataSource();
    var volumeModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Volume Chart" };
    var volume = new ColumnSeries
    {
        FillColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(255, 95, 95)
    };
    for (var i=0;  i< _fileData.DataItems.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = _fileData.DataItems[i];
        volume.Items.Add(new ColumnItem { Value = item.value });
    }
    volumeModel.Series.Add(volume);
    this.volumePlot.Model = volumeModel;
}
```

5 - для того что бы сохранить в `.pdf` :

```
 using (var stream = File.Create("Volume.pdf"))
 {
     var pdfExporter = new PdfExporter { Width = 13000, Height = 400 };
     pdfExporter.Export(volumeModel, stream);
 }
```

У меня был большой горафик поэтому и Width = 13000, но на качестве это не скажется.